# Calculating the number of possible outcomes with replacement and without replacement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Suppose you have a bag of groceries with $M$ distinct items. The items
> are either produce, animal products, toiletries, or grains. Consider a
> random draw from the bag of $D$ items and lay them all out in an
> (ordered) row. Let $N_r$ be the number of possible outcomes with
> replacement, $N_p$ be the number of possible outcomes without
> replacement, and $N_c$ be the number of possible categorical outcomes
> with replacement (i.e., produce - toiletries - grain - grain - ...).
> Assume there are at least $D$ items of each category.
>
> a) List $N_r$, $N_c$, and $N_p$ from smallest to largest.

$N_r = M^{D}$

$N_p = \frac{M!}{(M-D)!}$

$N_c=4^D$

$N_c < N_p < N_r$

> b) Calculate and order similar expressions for *unordered*
> collections.

$N_r = \frac{M^{D}}{D!}$

$N_p = \frac{M!}{(M-D)!}*\frac{1}{D!}$

$N_c=\frac{4^D}{D!}$

$N_c < N_p < N_r$

> c) Let $M=20, D=5$. Calculate $N_r, N_c, N_p$ and the ratios between
> them (ratios should be greater than 1)

$N_r = 20^{5}$

$N_p = \frac{20!}{(20-5)!}$

$N_c=4^5$

$\frac{N_r}{N_p}\approx 1.72$

$\frac{N_p}{N_c}\approx 1816.875$

$\frac{N_r}{N_c}\approx 3125$

> d) Now let $M=100, D=25$ Calculate the same values, and compare the
> ratios in this problem to the previous problem. Are they 5× larger?
> Explain why or why not.

$N_r = 100^{25}$

$N_p = \frac{100!}{(100-25)!}$

$N_c=4^{25}$

$\frac{N_r}{N_p}\approx 26.58$

$\frac{N_p}{N_c}\approx 3.34 *10^{33}$

$\frac{N_r}{N_c}\approx 8.88*10^{34}$

These values would be five times larger if this growth was linear. However, exponentials and factorials grow a lot faster, giving much larger values.

Is my answer correct?